# Por que o botão não alinha no ipad?

Tags: html, css

O responsivo do site está alinhando nos outros dispositivos tranquilamente porém no ipad ele sai do lugar... alguém sabe um modo de por ele no centro sem que perca a posição do centro para celulares? olha como ele está, se puderem dar uma olha no f12 o site é politicadascidades.com.br

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: aqui aparece centralizado...

Comment: Aqui também aparece centralizado no modo de visão do iPad, poderia verificar o que acontece?

Comment: e ai? o erro persiste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar o CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```